# How do I pass boolean Environmental Variables to a `when` step in CircleCI?

Tags: bash, circleci

I want to do something along the lines of

````
commands:
  send-slack:
    parameters:
      condition:
        type: env_var_name
    steps:
      - when:
          # only send if it's true
          condition: << parameters.condition >>
          steps:
            - run: # do some stuff if it's true
jobs:
  deploy:
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Prepare Message
          command: |
            # Do Some stuff dynamically to figure out what message to send
            # and save it to success_message or failure_message
            echo "export success_message=true" >> $BASH_ENV
            echo "export failure_message=false" >> $BASH_ENV
      - send-slack:
          text: "yay"
          condition: success_message

      - send-slack:
          text: "nay"
          condition: failure_message
    ```
````

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/reusing-config/#defining-conditional-steps) documentation, you cannot use environment variables as conditions in CircleCI. This is because the `when` logic is done when the configuration is processed (ie, before the job actually runs and the environment variables are set). As an alternative, I would add the logic to a separate run step (or the same initial one).

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Prepare Message
          command: |
            # Do Some stuff dynamically to figure out what message to send
            # and save it to success_message or failure_message
            echo "export success_message=true" >> $BASH_ENV
            echo "export failure_message=false" >> $BASH_ENV
      - run:
          name: Send Message
          command: |
            if $success_message; then 
                # Send success message
            fi 
            if $failure_message; then 
                # Send failure message
            fi
```

[Here](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/use-environment-variables-in-parameters/26314) is a relevant ticket on the CircleCI discussion board.